# Streaming your Linux desktop to a dynamic image in a browser window for anyone to see

Tags: linux, browser, vnc, streaming

I am trying to share the contents of a web page viewed on one computer and make it available to many computers in a simple to consume format via a browser. I would like to avoid java or other things that would require an additional install if possible. Lastly, the server which is viewing the page is the only computer authorized to view this page.

I have been looking around for a viable option to stream the contents of a VNC session to an animated GIF such as https://github.com/sidorares/vnc-over-gif, but I have had problems compiling vnc-over-gif with node, after spending an hour on it I am interested in exploring other options. I also tried [Guacamole](http://guac-dev.org/doc/gug/index.html), but it building it from source has like 50 things to install, and the package method just fails with some sort of dependency loop I seem to be too ignorant to figure out.

I do not want (and do not need) to control the screen, this should be a read only view of what is going on.

Google has many results on streaming a video format(ffmpeg, vlc) but in this case I specifically am going for something with a very simple method to view, hence the image formats.

Many thanks for any suggestions you have!

Comment: It will not be possible. Images are loaded once per page load, you need it to load continuously. HTML does not support it.

Comment: @soandos that's fair, but I could add some javascript to refresh the page. If that is a stopping point, do you have any ideas for the static image?

Comment: You would need a way to scape the screen every few seconds, and save that to a .gif. Then you would need to put that file in the correct location so that the js update code would find it.

Comment: I guess that is fair, I could do something as low tech as saving a screenshot every x seconds to a directory served by a webserver... I guess I hadnt considered such a low tech solution, but I cant find anything wrong with it! If you want to post that as an answer and I dont get a reasonable one soon, I will choose that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to scrape the screen every few seconds, and then save those pictures as a .gif. Then you would need to save it to a location where it can be served up by the webserver when the js requests it.

As an aside, this approach will limit you to a very low framerate (at best 1 a second or so).

Comment: I see no benefit to saving to a GIF. Why not just save it to a PNG (much better compression and looks better for screenshots)? You could have a single CurrentScreenshot.png, and then to force the cache to clear, change the image source every `n` seconds using JavaScript to point to `CurrentScreenshot.png?dummyvar=timestamp`.

Comment: @nhinkle this way you can store multiple screenshots into one file